# Simplified binary permutation summation

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

Consider the following function $f(n)$ defined as:
$$f(n):=\sum_{\{\bar{K}\}}\prod_{l<j}^{n}e^{ik_lk_j},$$ where $\{\bar{K}\}$ is the full set of binary permutations of length $n$ and $i$ denotes the complex number. Example for $n = 3$ we get $$\{\bar{K}\} = \{\{0, 0, 0\}, \{0, 0, 1\}, \{0, 1, 0\}, \{1, 0, 0\}, \{0, 1, 1\}, \{1, 0, 1\}, \{1, 1, 0\}, \{1, 1, 1\}\}.$$

**Question:**
Since the function depends only on $n$ is it clear if it has a more simplified analytic form which only contains variable $n$?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: is the $i$ in the exponent the literal variable $i$ or is it the imaginary $i$?

Comment: Can you let us know what your expected output is for n=2? If $\{K\}=\{00,01,10,11\}$ then what does $f(2)$ look like? Does $f(2)=e^{i (k_0 k_1)}$ or $f(2)=e^{i (0 \cdot 1)}$ or $f(2)=e^{(0)\cdot(k_0 \cdot k_1)}$?

Comment: @Phicar Apologies I have updated the question to correct the complex i ambiguity.

Comment: @JohnDoe Sure, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can split your sum filtering for how many ones are in the sequence $K$ say $k$ for example, if $k=1$ and $n=3$ then the sequence are $100,010,001$. In this way you have
$$f(n)=\sum _{k=0}^n\sum _{K\text{ has k ones}  }\prod _{\ell <j}e^{ik_{\ell}k_j},$$
notice that $k_{\ell}k_j=1$ iff both are $1$ so out of the $k$ ones you are picking $2$. The rest vanish and because the position really does not matter, the sum becomes $$f(n)=\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{i\binom{k}{2}},$$
not sure if you can simplify this.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.

Comment: Using the same reasoning as above, if we instead consider the function 
$$f(n):=\sum_{\underline{K}}\prod_{i<j}^{n}e^{i{(((k_i \oplus1)(k_j \oplus1))-(k_ik_j))  }},$$ where $\oplus$ denotes [the exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) logical operation and $k$ is again the number of ones in the sequence, then we can write the function as $$f(n) =\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{n-k}e^{i\binom{n-k}{2}}}{\binom{n}{k}e^{i\binom{k}{2}}}.$$ What do you think?

Comment: @JohnDoe It does make sense.